# Antialising / Fonts in Java/Netbeans

Tags: fonts, java, arch-linux

In the Netbeans editor, fonts look really ugly: [image: netbeans-fonts]

There are several suggestions in the [ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java_Runtime_Environment_Fonts) but they didn´t work for me.
What do I have to do to get a normal Netbeans experience with ArchLinux?

- `java -version`:

  java version "1.6.0_24"
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (ArchLinux-6.b24_1.11.1-3-x86_64)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Answer (score 3):

try this options:

> java -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true YOUR_JAR_FILE

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Java Swing apps like Netbeans look awful on Linux, but it's a lot better (. is not one pixel for example), when you set the editing font to bold in Netbeans options.

The problem has also been discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32624/ugly-fonts-in-netbeans-how-can-i-make-it-use-the-system-font).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and [this 'Font Rendering in NetBeans IDE' page at netbeans.org](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontRendering) helped me.

I changed parameters for option `netbeans_default_options` in my `netbeans.conf` file .